# Summary data on venture capital

Tags: reference-request, investment

Is there a trade group, government, or other publication providing data on aggregate venture capital investment?

Specifically, I'm interested in how overall venture capital funding has changed over time, how it is divided by sector, and how it is divided by funding stage.

I'm specifically interested in data for the US.

Answer (score 1):

The best resource I've found so far is [Pitchbook's quarterly summary](https://files.pitchbook.com/website/files/pdf/1Q_2018_PitchBook_NVCA_Venture_Monitor.pdf). It includes some degree of historical data, historical data by funding stage, and historical data by sector.